# variable name not recognised in sql query

Tags: php, sql

im writing a register page using html,php and javascript. i have written the following code

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','private_message');

 if(isset($_POST['user'])){
    $usrname=(string)$_POST['user'];
    echo gettype($usrname);
    $r=mysqli_query($db ,"select * from users where 'user_name'='$usrname' ") or die("error");

    $rows=mysqli_num_rows($r);
    echo "";
    echo $rows;
 }

 ?>
```

now my table has user name 'hello' but the above $usrname  is not recognised in the part 'user_name'='$usrname' part. what do i do?

Comment: If is treating `'user_name'` as a literal, should be in backticks `\`user_name\``.  BUT you should be using prepared statements instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Make SQl query as follows `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$usrname."'";` then try `$r  = mysqli_query($db ,$sql) or die("error");`